# bash terminal - prompt cursor changes from $ to > upon entering invalid command

Tags: command-line, unix, bash, shell, terminal.app

I used the Terminal application in Mac OS X to remove some hidden files (i believe this uses the bash shell by default). I inadvertently misspelt my command and, upon hitting the Enter key, my prompt cursor changed from:

```
username$
```

to simply:

```
>
```

I could only exit to the previos cursor with CTRL + D. Had I entered a sub-session for a different shell? Why did this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started a shell structure (quoted string, for or while loop, etc.) and bash was waiting for you to complete it. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to abort the command.

Comment: @EddieCatflap: It's known as the PS2 secondary prompt. See "Prompting" in `man bash`.

Comment: Ok now I know why the shell was behaving like this and it makes much more sense now that I have read further on the topic, thank you guys.